# Is watching ecchi anime haram?

Tags: sin

Is it haram to watch ecchi anime that only shows the top part of a woman breast but not the nipples or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

See Brother anime is like a TV show just in animated from.

And the thing you are saying is Haram because you are attracted to the woman even thou she is not real. You might feel aroused(erection) so it is 100% haram/sin.

It is just like watching a real woman.

ALLAH knows the best..